Initializing an array created with malloc with arbitrary values
I need to create large float arrays using malloc, to be able to free the memory when I don't need the array anymore.
The values are arbitrary, meaning they are not all zeros or ones, much more random but coming from computations from another code. They can be stored in a .h file.
I first do the memory allocation (here with a small size, for commodity):
float* x;
x = (float *) malloc (5 *sizeof(float)) ;

Then I want to initialize the array with the values, such as:
x = { 1.0, 2.2, 3.6, 5.4, 8.4 };

But I get a compilation error:

error: cannot convert '' to 'float*'
in assignment

What is the correct way to do this initalization?
Thanks for your help.

You can't initialize memory returned from malloc, you need to assign to it instead.  You can't assign entire arrays in C, so you need to do it element-wise, or memcpy from another array.  So you choice is to assign each element in turn, or create a static or automatic initialized array with the data you want and memcpy from that.

It is worth asking if the data is expected to be mutable or constant. Can your array be const? Or will you need to modify the data during its use?

C does not provide any initialization for dynamically allocated memory. Depending on your real use case, acceptable ways could include 1/ do not use malloc but static duration or automatic objects (both can be initialized) or 2/ do not use initialization but copy (memcpy?) static values to the newly allocated array.


What is the correct way to do this initialization?

Initialization has a special meaning in C in that it occurs when the value an object is assigned when it is created.
Here, it is better described as assignment as the value assignments occur after object creation.
Code could use a compound literal of 5 floats..
  //                  v            compound literal           v
  #define FIRST_DATA  (float[]){ 1.0f, 2.2f, 3.6f, 5.4f, 8.4f }
  float *x = malloc(sizeof FIRST_DATA);
  if (x) {
    memcpy(x, FIRST_DATA, sizeof FIRST_DATA);
    // ...
    free(x); // Free when done.
  }

Or more conventionally with a separate object:
  float first_data[] = { 1.0f, 2.2f, 3.6f, 5.4f, 8.4f };
  float *x = malloc(sizeof first_data);
  if (x) {
    memcpy(x, first_data, sizeof first_data);
    // ...
    free(x); // Free when done.
  }

Or perhaps one at a time...
  #define N 500000
  float *x = malloc(sizeof x[0] * N);
  if (x) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      x[i] = (float) rand();
    }
    // ...
    free(x); // Free when done.
  }


In general it is possible like this
typedef struct {
    float v[5];
} f5_t;

const f5_t a =  {
    .v = { 1.0, 2.2, 3.6, 5.4, 8.4 }
};

void my_func(void)
{
    f5_t *x;
    
    x = (f5_t *) malloc(sizeof(f5_t));
    *x = a; 
    
    ...
}

but dynamic memory allocation does not have sense if you need only one instance of data, you already have to use memory to store the initializing values in one or another way.

"does not have any sense" Not so... There are many use cases wherein a collection of "standard" initial values (compile time) are copied to multiple dynamic mutable instances, each to go on to evolve along its own path. Bacteria dividing provide a biological analogue to what happens with "boilerplate" origins... (PS: the casting is unnecessary.)

@legden, rather than use double constants to assign a float, betters to assign float constants. .v = { 1.0f, 2.2f, 3.6f, 5.4f, 8.4f }.

@Fe2O3 Yes, in such cases it makes sense.
